# System.typeInitializationException on Windows phone

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, windows-phone-8.1, stack-overflow

I am getting this exception when I am trying to debug my application by connecting a device. It is working fine in the emulator with no exceptions at all.

The InnerException is: Could not load file or assembly 'BouncyCastle.Crypto, Version=1.8.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0e99375e54769942' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

But the file is present with the specific version and token.

In StackTrace it showing that exception is occured here : setDefaultLanguageFromCode(String selectedLanguage)

Here's the code:

```
 private void Application_Launching(object sender, LaunchingEventArgs e)
    {
     ...//some code

        Utility.setDefaultLanguageFromCode(code);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
        LocalizedStringsInCommonDll.LocalizedStringsResource.UpdateLanguage();
    }
```

In Utility Page :

```
 public static System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo input = new System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo();
 public static void setDefaultLanguageFromCode(string selectedLanguage)
    {
        input.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";//**Exception here**
        input.NumberGroupSeparator = ",";
    ......
    }
```

Is the exception caused due to some settings on device. 
I tried google search but nothing helped me..

I am desperately in need of help.. I have already wasted an entire day behind this trying to figure out what is wrong here..

Comment: I run your code in C# Console and do not get any exception or errors

Comment: I am getting this exception only when I run it on device.. on emulator it is not throwing any exception

Comment: I code on Android mobile not windows phone.. could you be missing some assembly's on the device have you tried a google or msdn search about Globalization on windows phone..?

Comment: InnerException :Could not load file or assembly 'BouncyCastle.Crypto'. But the file is already included .

Comment: do a google search on the error referencing Windows Phone in your search

Comment: no Application_Launching LaunchingEventArgs in wp8.1 project, is it silverlight project ?

Comment: No , its is not a silverlight project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to reinstall BouncyCastle crypto by using this in Package manager console

***Install-Package Portable.BouncyCastle -Version 1.8.1.3***

and it resolved my issue..